# How to fix compiler error: cannot convert to a pointer type with Cython + numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to wrap a C function for use in Python using Cython and numpy.

When I compile I get the following error:

```
_fastlp.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6fastlp_fastlp_func’:
_fastlp.c:1351:3: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
   fastlp(((double *)PyArray_DATA(((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_v_obj))), 
   ((double *)PyArray_DATA(((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_v_mat))), 
   ((double *)PyArray_DATA(((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_v_rhs))), (&__pyx_v_m0), 
   (&__pyx_v_n0), ((double *)PyArray_DATA(__pyx_v_opt)), 
   (&__pyx_v_status), ((double *)__pyx_v_lam));
      ^
```

The arrow `^` points to `(&__pyx_v_status)`.

My `.pyx` file is:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()

# cdefine the signature of the c function
cdef extern from "fastlp.h":
    void fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, 
                double *opt, int *status, double *lam)

def fastlp_func(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] obj not None,
                np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] mat not None,
                np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] rhs not None,
                double lam):   

    #Define output
    cdef np.ndarray opt = np.zeros((len(obj),), dtype = np.float64)
    cdef int status = 0

    #Call external C function
    cdef int m0 = mat.shape[0]
    cdef int n0 = mat.shape[1]

    fastlp(<double*> np.PyArray_DATA(obj),
           <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(mat),
           <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(rhs),
           &m0,
           &n0,
           <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(opt),
           &status,
           <double*> lam)

    return (opt,status)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I've been working on this for so long and I think I'm close. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that all I needed was to use `<double*> &lam` in calling the external function. I was trying to cast a variable to a pointer...when I shouldn't have.